# Divisor of rational function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am finding the divisor of $f = (x_1/x_0) − 1 $ on $C$, where $C = V ( x_1^2 + x_2 ^2 − x_0^ 2 ) ⊂ \mathbb P^ 2 $. Characteristic is not 2.

I am totally new to divisors. So the plan in my mind is first find an open subset $U$ of $C$. In this case maybe it should be the complement of $X={x_2=0}$. Then I should look at $\text{ord}(f)$ on this $U$. Then I get confused, since $f$ is a rational function, how can $f$ belong to $k[U]$?

I know this is a stupid question, by the way.

Comment: Your question is not stupid at all: it illustrates the difficulty of using homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s how I would do it, but my method and understanding are irremediably old-fashioned, to the extent that they may be of limited assistance to you.

First, I would take the open set where $x_0\ne0$, and dehomogenize by setting $x_0=1$, to get $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$, the unit circle! The function $f$ is now $x-1$, and this clearly has a double zero at $(1,0)$ in the affine plane, corresponding to the projective point $(1:1:0)$. Since $f$ certainly has no poles in the affine $(x_1,x_2)$-plane, the poles must lie on the line $x_0=0$, so we’re looking for points on our conic of form $(0:x:y)$. But there you are: they are $(0:1:i)$ and $(1:-i:0)=(0:i:1)$.

The upshot? The divisor is $2(1:1:0)-(0:1:i)-(0:i:1)$.

Let me add for an amusing point that your curve is a circle, and if you’re applying the theorem of Bézout that says that in the projective plane, a curve of degree $d_1$ and a curve of degree $d_2$ will always have $d_1d_2$ points of intersection, the four points of intersection of two circles are the two points that you know about from high-school geometry, together with the points $(x:y:z)=(1:i:0)$ and $(i:1:0)$, through which *every* circle passes.

Comment: Dear Lubin, I was composing my answer while you posted yours and I'm very happy and flattered that we gave such similar answers. Moreover, I very much doubt that our "irremediably old-fashioned understanding and method" has been superseded  by the $\aleph_0$ apps on the  avalanche of models of iPhones...

Answer (score 3):

Your curve is a circle which in the affine plane $U_0:x_0\neq0$ has equation $x^2+y^2-1=0$ in the affine coordinates $x=\frac {x_1}{x_0}, y=\frac {x_2}{x_0}$.
The function $f$ restricted to $C_0=C\cap U_0$ can be written $f(x,y)=x-1$. 
It should be pretty clear that its divisor is $(\operatorname {div}f)\vert C_0=2\cdot P$ where $P=(1,0)=[1:1:0]$.
At the points at infinity of $C$ , namely $\infty_+=[0:1:i],\infty_-=[0:1:-i]$, use the coordinates $u=\frac {x_0}{x_1}, v=\frac {x_2}{x_1}$.
Then near these points $C$ has equation $1+v^2-u^2=0$, the point $\infty_+$ has coordinates $(u=0,v=i)$ and the function $f$ has the expression $f=\frac {1-u}{u}$ .
Since $u$ is a uniformizing parameter at  $\infty_+$ for $C$ we see that $(\operatorname {div}f)(\infty_+)=-1$.
Similarly  $(\operatorname {div}f)(\infty_-)=-1$ and finally we get $$ \operatorname {div}f=2\cdot P- 1\cdot \infty_+     - 1\cdot \infty_-    $$ Note that that the degree of that divisor is zero, just as it should.

Comment: Dear Georges, since Lubin posted the answer a little bit earlier I choose that is answer but as you said the two answers are very similar and good. By the way, can I also do this problem in the following way. The prime divisor for C is just point. And if ord(f) is positive on some point, then $x_1-x_0=0$ at this point. So I just figure out the at which point $x_1-x_0=0$ and at which point $x_0=0$. The result is the same, so can I also do it in this way?

Comment: Dear Learning, it was an excellent and fair decision to choose the earlier answer of the two. Your method is morally right but would take some effort to be formalized as a general proposition.